# Error meesage is coming: HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name

Tags: java, struts2

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false"/>


    <package name="loginPkg"  extends="struts-default">
        <global-results>
            <result name="unhandledException">/unhandled-exception.jsp</result>
        </global-results>

        <global-exception-mappings>
            <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="unhandledException"/>
        </global-exception-mappings>
        <action name="Login" class="loginPkg.Login_validate">
            <result name="success">/Home.jsp</result>
            <result name="admin">/AdminHome.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/empLogin.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="logout" class="loginPkg.Logout">
            <result name="success">/Logout.jsp</result>
            <result name="logout" type="redirect">/Logout.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="empforgot_pass" class="loginPkg.forgotPswd">
            <result name="success">/empForgotPass.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="empForgotPass" method="display" class="loginPkg.forgotPswd">
            <result name="none">/empForgotPass.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>


</struts>
```

when I am running my application its giving me some sort of the error

```
HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name .
```

Comment: What request are you making?

Comment: How are you calling the action?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting errors because you forget to set the `namespace` attribute of the package declaration. Struts2 is trying to get the mapping for the request you've made but without namespace it can't create mapping for you thus the action can't be called and result is 404. Use

```
<package name="loginPkg"  namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
```

Comment: A namespace of "/" is not required.